# Issue with Apache archiva-js-1.4-M3?

Tags: archiva

I Created a Repository in the Apache archiva and added all the jars in that repository and using this apache archiva repository in my Pom.xml file. But when i am trying...

> mvn eclipse:eclipse

it downloaded all jars into .m2 directory but each jar size is 3Kb . I checked all jars size in Archiva and it is ok there. I am not able to figure out where is the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution of the issue i have to enable Guest user for my repository also.Please have a look on attached screen shot.
[image]